# Tkinter is not running on Heroku server but it is running fine on Local host

Tags: python, flask, heroku, tkinter

I am developing a web app using flask similarly like virtual dressing room where users can try clothes on them. I am using dlib to perform all the landmark detections so that I can find the position to superimpose my image such that it looks like person is wearing that cloth. 
I am using Tkinter to serve camera and images in a single GUI window, see this image below
[image: Tkinter GUI window]

Everything works fine at local host, but when I deploy it on Heroku the tkinter is not running it redirects the website to local host address. All the logic is in test.py file, please have a look at this file ->

```
from tkinter_scroll import *
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import cv2, threading, os, time
from threading import Thread
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import dlib
from imutils import face_utils, rotate_bound
import math

ACTIVE_IMAGES=[0 for i in range(100)]
def put_sprite(num, k):
    global SPRITES, BTNS
    SPRITES[num] = (1 - SPRITES[num]) 
    if SPRITES[num]:
        ACTIVE_IMAGES[num] = k
        BTNS[num].config(relief=SUNKEN)
    else:
        BTNS[num].config(relief=RAISED)

def draw_sprite(frame, sprite, x_offset, y_offset):
    (h,w) = (sprite.shape[0], sprite.shape[1])
    (imgH,imgW) = (frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1])
    if y_offset+h >= imgH:
        sprite = sprite[0:imgH-y_offset,:,:]
    if x_offset+w >= imgW:
        sprite = sprite[:,0:imgW-x_offset,:]
    if x_offset < 0: 
        sprite = sprite[:,abs(x_offset)::,:]
        w = sprite.shape[1]
        x_offset = 0
    for c in range(3):
            frame[y_offset:y_offset+h, x_offset:x_offset+w, c] =  \
            sprite[:,:,c] * (sprite[:,:,3]/255.0) +  frame[y_offset:y_offset+h, x_offset:x_offset+w, c] * (1.0 - sprite[:,:,3]/255.0)
    return frame

def adjust_sprite2head(sprite, head_width, head_ypos, ontop = True):
    (h_sprite,w_sprite) = (sprite.shape[0], sprite.shape[1])
    factor = 1.0*head_width/w_sprite
    sprite = cv2.resize(sprite, (0,0), fx=factor, fy=factor)
    (h_sprite,w_sprite) = (sprite.shape[0], sprite.shape[1])
    y_orig =  head_ypos-h_sprite if ontop else head_ypos 
    if (y_orig < 0):
            sprite = sprite[abs(y_orig)::,:,:] 
            y_orig = 0
    return (sprite, y_orig)

def apply_sprite2feature(image, sprite_path, haar_filter, x_offset, y_offset, y_offset_image, adjust2feature, desired_width, x, y, w, h):
    sprite = cv2.imread(sprite_path,-1)
    (h_sprite,w_sprite) = (sprite.shape[0], sprite.shape[1])

    xpos = x + x_offset
    ypos = y + y_offset
    factor = 1.0*desired_width/w_sprite

    sub_img = image[y + y_offset_image:y+h,x:x+w,:]

    feature = apply_Haar_filter(sub_img, haar_filter, 1.3 , 10, 10)
    if len(feature)!=0:
        xpos, ypos = x, y + feature[0,1] #adjust only to feature in y axis (eyes)

        if adjust2feature:
            size_mustache = 1.2 #how many times bigger than mouth
            factor = 1.0*(feature[0,2]*size_mustache)/w_sprite
            xpos =  x + feature[0,0] - int(feature[0,2]*(size_mustache-1)//2) #centered respect to width
            ypos = y + y_offset_image + feature[0,1] - int(h_sprite*factor) #right on top

    sprite = cv2.resize(sprite, (0,0), fx=factor, fy=factor)
    image = draw_sprite(image,sprite,xpos,ypos)

def apply_sprite(image, path2sprite,w,x,y, angle, ontop = True):
    sprite = cv2.imread(path2sprite,-1)
    sprite = rotate_bound(sprite, angle)
    (sprite, y_final) = adjust_sprite2head(sprite, w, y, ontop)
    image = draw_sprite(image,sprite,x, y_final)

def calculate_inclination(point1, point2):
    x1,x2,y1,y2 = point1[0], point2[0], point1[1], point2[1]
    incl = 180/math.pi*math.atan((float(y2-y1))/(x2-x1))
    return incl

def calculate_boundbox(list_coordinates):
    x = min(list_coordinates[:,0])
    y = min(list_coordinates[:,1])
    w = max(list_coordinates[:,0]) - x
    h = max(list_coordinates[:,1]) - y
    return (x,y,w,h)

def apply_Haar_filter(img, haar_cascade,scaleFact = 1.05, minNeigh = 3, minSizeW = 30):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    features = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=scaleFact,
        minNeighbors=minNeigh,
        minSize=(minSizeW, minSizeW),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )
    return features


def get_face_boundbox(points, face_part):
    if face_part == 1:
        (x,y,w,h) = calculate_boundbox(points[17:22])
    elif face_part == 2:
        (x,y,w,h) = calculate_boundbox(points[22:27]) 
    elif face_part == 3:
        (x,y,w,h) = calculate_boundbox(points[36:42])
    elif face_part == 4:
        (x,y,w,h) = calculate_boundbox(points[42:48])
    elif face_part == 5:
        (x,y,w,h) = calculate_boundbox(points[29:36])
    elif face_part == 6:  
        (x,y,w,h) = calculate_boundbox(points[1:17])
    elif face_part == 7:
         (x,y,w,h) = calculate_boundbox(points[0:6])
    elif face_part == 8:
        (x,y,w,h) = calculate_boundbox(points[11:17])
    return (x,y,w,h)

def cvloop(run_event):
    global ctr_mid
    global SPRITES
    i = 0
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    video_capture.set(3,2048)
    video_capture.set(4,2048)
    (x,y,w,h) = (0,0,10,10) 
    detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
    fullbody = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
    model = "data/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(model) # link to model: http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2
    while run_event.is_set(): 
        ret, image = video_capture.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = detector(gray, 0)
        for face in faces: 
            (x,y,w,h) = (face.left(), face.top(), face.width(), face.height())
            shape = predictor(gray, face)
            shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
            incl = calculate_inclination(shape[17], shape[26])
            is_mouth_open = (shape[66][1] -shape[62][1]) >= 10

            if SPRITES[3]:#Tiara
                apply_sprite(image, IMAGES[3][ACTIVE_IMAGES[3]],w+45,x-20,y+20, incl, ontop = True)

            #Necklaces
            if SPRITES[1]:
                (x1,y1,w1,h1) = get_face_boundbox(shape, 6)
                apply_sprite(image, IMAGES[1][ACTIVE_IMAGES[1]],w1,x1,y1+150, incl,  ontop = False)

            #Goggles
            if SPRITES[6]:
                (x3,y3,_,h3) = get_face_boundbox(shape, 1)
                apply_sprite(image, IMAGES[6][ACTIVE_IMAGES[6]],w,x,y3-10, incl, ontop = False)

            #Earrings
            (x0,y0,w0,h0) = get_face_boundbox(shape, 6) #bound box of mouth
            if SPRITES[2]:
                (x3,y3,w3,h3) = get_face_boundbox(shape, 7) #nose
                apply_sprite(image, IMAGES[2][ACTIVE_IMAGES[2]],w3,x3-40,y3+30, incl,ontop=False)
                (x3,y3,w3,h3) = get_face_boundbox(shape, 8) #nose
                apply_sprite(image, IMAGES[2][ACTIVE_IMAGES[2]],w3,x3+40,y3+75, incl) 

#            if SPRITES[5]:
#                apply_sprite(image, IMAGES[5][ACTIVE_IMAGES[5]],w,x,y, incl, ontop = True)

            #Frocks
            if SPRITES[5]:
                (x1,y1,w1,h1) = get_face_boundbox(shape, 8)
                apply_sprite(image, IMAGES[5][ACTIVE_IMAGES[5]],w1+580,x1-350,y1+80, incl,  ontop = False)

            #Tops
            if SPRITES[4]:
                # (x,y,w,h) = (0,0,10,10)
                # apply_sprite2feature(image, IMAGES[7][ACTIVE_IMAGES[7]], fullbody, w//4, 2*h//3, h//2, True, w//2, x, y, w, h)
                (x1,y1,w1,h1) = get_face_boundbox(shape, 8)
                apply_sprite(image, IMAGES[4][ACTIVE_IMAGES[4]],w1+350,x1-230,y1+100, incl,  ontop = False)

        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = Image.fromarray(image)
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        ctr_mid.configure(image=image)
        ctr_mid.image = image

    video_capture.release()

root = Tk()
root.title('TryOn')
app=FullScreenApp(root)

top_frame = Frame(root, bg='#077bd4', width=50, height=50, pady=3)
center = Frame(root, bg='white', width=50, height=40, padx=3, pady=3)
btm_frame = Frame(root, bg='#077bd4', width=50, height=50, pady=3)

root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

top_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
center.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")
btm_frame.grid(row=4, sticky="ew")
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('logo.png').resize((120,60)))
model_label = Label(top_frame,image=logo)

model_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

center.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
center.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

ctr_left = Label(center,bg='white', width=50, height=190)
ctr_mid = Label(center,bg='white',width=100, height=160, padx=0, pady=0)

ctr_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
ctr_mid.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

scrollable_body = Scrollable(ctr_left, width=15)
SPRITES=[0 for i in range(10)]
BTNS=[]
IMAGES ={i:[] for i in range(10)}
PHOTOS ={i:[] for i in range(10)}
for img in sys.argv[1:]:
    print(img.rsplit('/',1)[0][-1])
    IMAGES[int(img.rsplit('/',1)[0][-1])].append(img)
    image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img).resize((150,100)))
    PHOTOS[int(img.rsplit('/',1)[0][-1])].append(image)
for index in range(9):
    if len(PHOTOS[index]) > 0:
        for k,photo in enumerate(PHOTOS[index]):
            btn= Button(scrollable_body, highlightbackground='white', text=IMAGES[index][k].rsplit('/',1)[1].replace('.png','')[:-1],bg='white', image=photo, command = lambda index=index, k=k: put_sprite(index,k), compound=LEFT, width='300', height='200')
            btn.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no", padx="5", pady="5")
            BTNS.append(btn)
scrollable_body.update()

run_event = threading.Event()
run_event.set()
action = Thread(target=cvloop, args=(run_event,))
action.setDaemon(True)
action.start()

def terminate():
        global root, run_event, action
        run_event.clear()
        time.sleep(1)
        root.destroy()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", terminate)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to resolve this problem, if it is not possible to run tkinter on server then please tell me some other way to achieve this type of functionality.

Comment: You say you're developing a web app, and that's certainly the kind of thing you could deploy to Heroku, but Tkinter is a *desktop* GUI framework.

Comment: When hosting locally you can't visit Tkinter from your web browser. This means you also can't host it on a server and expect to be able to visit it from a web browser.

Comment: okay, Is there any other way I can use GUI on servers or what else I can do ?

Comment: Basically I want to launch camera at client side with some images